# Internet Explorer 8 error, Object Required (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I wrote a todo in chrome that works fine.  I tested it in IE8 and it didn't work.  So I made a new file to write specifically in IE8, and I can't even get a simple function to work properly.   I would like help in finding out what i'm doing wrong.  Thank you to anyone that can school me on this.

HTML

```
<body>
<p>Home</p>
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" id="inItemText" />
</form>
<button id="btn1" onclick="doIt()">Press Here</button>
<p id="p1"></p>
</body>
```

Javascript

```
var inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");
function doIt() {
var itemText;
itemText = inItemText.value;
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = itemText;
form1.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you do the `inItemText` assignment after the DOM has been loaded. Otherwise, `document.getElementById("inItemText")` won't find the element, because it doesn't exist yet.

Either put it at the end of the `<body>`, or use `window.onload`:

```
var inItemText;
window.onload = function() {
    inItemText = document.getElementById("inItemText");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because `inItemText` isn't defined. Use `document.getElementById('inItemText')`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in this line:

```
itemText = inItemText.value;
```

You need to declare "inItemText" as a variable.

Perhaps replace it with:

```
itemText = document.getElementById("inItemText").value
```

Comment: He has that assignment right before the function definition.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thank you.  If you have time, can you explain why the code works in chrome, but not IE? And would it be a good practice to just write all my code to work in IE? A lot of stuff i did while learning never works in IE.

Comment: btw, i also erased the assignment that is before the function, as Barmar alluded.

Comment: Ah, you are correct Barmar, my mistake.  Does it not work because the variable is out of scope or because it didn't find the element because the DOM wasn't loaded?

Comment: i wish i can accept both of your comments.  They both helped in this small file and the larger one that inspired the troubleshooting.